# Adding multiple properties to constant for payload all at once in React

Tags: reactjs

I have 1 parameter passed to profile as so:

```
profile.uniqueIdentifier = uuidv4();
```

Now I want to add 2 more: `browserInfo` and `amount` to my profile

```
browserInfo: {
   userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 Safari/537.36",
   acceptHeader: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml",
}
amount: {
   value: 0,
   currency
}
```

So that the final payload looks like so:

```
profile: {
   uniqueIdentifier: "9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d",
   browserInfo: {
      userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 Safari/537.36",
      acceptHeader: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml",
   },
   amount: {
      value: 0,
      currency
   }
}
```

Can I add all 3 all at once or do I have to add them 1 by 1 as so:

```
if(needBrowserInfo) {
   profile.uniqueIdentifier = uuidv4();
   profile.browserInfo = browserInfoConstant;
   profile.amount = amountConstant;
}
const payload = getPayload({
   billingInfo: someBillingInfo,
   profile
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using Object.assign;

```
if(needBrowserInfo) {
   const browserData = {
      uniqueIdentifier: "9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d",
      browserInfo: {
         userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 Safari/537.36",
         acceptHeader: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml",
      },
      amount: {
         value: 0,
         currency
      }
   };
   Object.assign(profile, browserData);
}

const payload = getPayload({
   billingInfo: someBillingInfo,
   profile
})
```